# Created Custom Fields not updating Templates in Appearance Editor

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have inherited a Wordpress project from someone else and have created new Custom Fields in Custom Fields > Custom Fields. However, when I go into Appearance > Editor they are not listed under "Templates" on the right? The original templates I inherited that the other guy made are there, but not the ones I created in Custom Fields?

Comment: Seems like you are approaching it incorrectly.  Custom fields have nothing to do with Appearance > editor ... Please explain in detail.  Are you saying their is php file of old custom fileds from old developer in theme folder, which means he used custom metaboxes api of WordPress. ... However if you creating custom fileds using WP post editor gui, then no you will not have any php file to edit in Appearance > Editor (it is theme editor)

Comment: I thought themes consisted of templates which were .php files?

Comment: Yes .php files,  style.css , and js files all can be part of a WordPress theme. What you're trying to achieve?  A custom fields box below posts , already created and displayed which you can control from theme files? I suggest you look into advanced custom fields plugin or cmb2 php class on github.

Comment: I need a decent guide for creating WP websites from a developers POV not someone who has never seen HTML, CSS, JS, PHP etc. like most guides.

Comment: I want to create new templates for additional webpages.

Comment: Please go here https://codex.wordpress.org read sections about Theme Development and Plugin Development.

Comment: Thats is called Page templates.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates

Comment: Please check this tutorial also to give you background info that WordPress theme custom page templates can be created http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-custom-page-templates-in-wordpress/